# How to show reocords based on previous and next row using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I have following records in database:- [Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM4rm.png)

[image]
Basically i want those records from **Table1** that only Asserted but not Cleared from **Alert** column I have highlighted in Table1.

> If you see in **Alert** column **HD** of Record20,**C2** of Record14 and **L1** of Record21 columns are only **ASSERTED** But not **CLEARED**. 
>   Show i want to show those records from **Alert** column which **ASSERTED** but not **CLEARED** using sql server.

Comment: Please don't post images of data, it isn't helpful to the volunteers you're asking help from. Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2008 though? That version is as good as completely out of support and this checking the values of the previous/next row is trivial in SQL Server 2012+ by using `LEAD`/`LAG`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
select t1.*
from t t1
where alerts like '%Asserted%' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.alerts like '%Cleared%' and
                        t2.alerts like left(t1.alerts, charindex(' ', t1.alerts)) + '%'
                 );
```

You should really fix the data model so the entity with the alarm is in a separate column.

Comment: Will this also capture Alarms which are repeating like H1 asserted and cleared two times in the OP's data, what if it is not cleared in the second time will it get included?

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran Yes that should also include

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran . . . The question states:  "Basically i want those records from Table1 that only Asserted but not Cleared from Alert column I have highlighted in Table1.".

Comment: @GordonLinoff Noted, OP requires that as well as per the comment given later.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select * from tbl where replace(Alerts, 'Asserted','') in
(
Select replace(Alerts, 'Asserted', '') a from tbl
where Alerts like '%Asserted%'
except
select replace(Alerts, 'Cleared','') a  from tbl
where Alerts like '%Cleared%' 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this WHERE condition to test that column

```
SELECT Alerts
FROM Table1
WHERE 
Alerts LIKE '%Asserted%'
AND
Alerts NOT LIKE '%Cleared%';
```

Modify the first row to include whatever other columns you want, as I only for simplicity and readability used to show only the column which will be tested against conditions.

Comment: This query will output all the rows which has 'Asserted' in Alerts.

Comment: @Nikola Pavlovic:- But this query will give all the records having Asserted. If see in table. `C1 is asserted and cleared as well ie RECORD No. 10 & 11` but if you see `C2 i.e RECORD No.14 is only asserted but never cleared. ` I want those records which ASSERTED but never CLEARED like C2

Comment: You really ought to improve your data model and give more information. Based on the snapshot, you either have a "Cleared" or "Asserted" in the alerts column. Based on that, my query will work for you.

What is "C2" of Record14?
What is "L1" of Record20?

We obviously don't see apparently all the data relevant, which you have stored in an Excel sheet, or compatible software. 
Are C2 and L1 referring to relative locations in the spreadsheet???

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
create table tblRecord (record varchar(10), tempText Varchar(20))
insert into tblRecord values
('record1', 'a1 asserted'),('record1', 'a1 cleared'),('record2', 'a2 asserted'),('record2', 'a2 cleared'),('record3', 'a3 asserted')

Select * from tblRecord where tempText like '%asserted%' --To get the records with asserted values
and record not in --To remove the records with cleared values
(
select record from tblRecord 
where REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(tempText), CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(tempText))- 1)) = 'cleared' --Last word
)
```

[Live Demo](https://rextester.com/VUEYPX58371)